# How to find OA free to publish journals with a JCR ranking?

Tags: publications, journals, open-access, ranking

I would like to find journals that:

- are ranked with JCR (no matter how low) *and*
- have open access (anyone can access the papers for free) *and*
- are free to publish (authors are not required to pay)

Maybe I am asking for a unicorn, but I think this should be feasible. 
If I'm not mistaken, [arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/) only fails in the first point. If someone could provide (a link to) a list of such a kind of journals that would be awesome. If such a list does not exist, how would I go about creating a list.

Comment: [_Journal of Machine Learning Research_](http://jmlr.org/) is perhaps the most successful example in computer science.  [Stuart Schieber's description of the journal's internal structure](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/pamphlet/2012/03/06/an-efficient-journal/) is amazing.  (On the other hand, arxiv.org fails because it's not a journal; arXiv papers are _not_ peer-reviewed.)

Comment: There are very, very, very, very many journals out there.  I think the question would be improved if you specifically limited it to a field (rather than *I prefer*, specify what you *need*).

Comment: The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics also fits your criteria.

Comment: @gerrit this is great, I didn't know there was any. Do you think it may make sense to create a wiki post so that people can edit and collaboratively generate a list? (possibly categorized by area/field/topic)

Comment: @JeffE if it is ranked in JCR, I (personally, sorry for this) don't mind about any review process. arxiv.org is not reviewed but papers there are cited, the utility/usefulness of the review process is doubtful when that is happening, it may even be negative (although that is a completely different topic).

Comment: Do you care about JCR specifically, or are other indexing services like Scopus acceptable?

Comment: @JeffE I care about JCR because the government, institutions and pretty much everyone cares about JCR (at least here, in Spain). I don't know whether there are services that are comparable to JCR in some other country or how widespread is the use of JCR as the standard to rate publications. Depending on that, those services could be more or less interesting. I hope the citation metrics will be similar or correlated in any case, at least.

Comment: If I am wrong, please let me know, but this question reads as primarily a "please list me journals that possess qualities X, Y, and Z". These question types are frowned upon for all SE sites. As there are already a few other close votes on this question, I'm going to cast the final vote; please comment if you think this question should be an exception to the general rule.

Comment: @eykanal that is how I read it also, I edited it to try and make it a better fit.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub - Thanks, that looks better to me.

Comment: arXiv.org also failed because it is a repository, not a journal.

Comment: @PhilipGibbs being a ranked journal implies being a journal, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: arXiv is not an academic journal because it does not have peer-review. It makes no difference if someone gives it a ranking or lists it as if it were a journal.

Comment: @PhilipGibbs there are academic journals that are not peer-reviewed. If something is defined as a journal, it's a journal (by definition).

Answer (score 4):

Please feel free to edit anything.

- Computer Science

  - Artificial Intelligence

    - Machine Learning

      - [Journal of Machine Learning Research](http://jmlr.org/)
  - General

    - [Journal of Universal Computer Science](http://www.jucs.org/)
- Mathematics

  - Combinatorics

    - [The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics](http://www.combinatorics.org/)
  - Statistics

    - [Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/)

Comment: I removed TSWJ since it is published by Hinadwi which Beall considers to be a borderline predatory publisher and it has an [APC](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/apc/)

Comment: I am down voting because I think that this type of list goes against the types of answers that are best suited for the SE network. It is going to be an hugely incomplete and maintainable list.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub  There are longer and more dynamic lists on wikipedia. Sure this is a hell lot of work for a single person, but not for a community, IMHO. If SE cannot handle this, then where? I'm not sure about how well will wikipedia work for this, but I guess I'll try in a week or so if this question remains closed.

Comment: part of the SE philosophy is that just because something doesn't fit someplace else doesn't mean it fits here. I would guess that there are 1000s of journals that meet the requirements. This answer is not going to provide an efficient way of accessing the information.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub there are 11K journals in JCR, out of those most do not provide OA, out of those with OA most charge authors (for publishing, processing, etc.) It's already surprising that there is *any* journal with these characteristics, I guesstimate the list cannot have more than one hundred journals by any means. But I can agree such a list may not be the best solution. I'll try to think about something else.

Comment: For mathematics, there is also SIGMA (http://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/).

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps not exactly what you look for but, as a partial answer, the [Advanced Search](http://doaj.org/search) feature of the directory of open access journals (DOAJ) lets you filter the open access journals by subject AND by publication fee. Unfortunately, you cannot infer from the DOAJ data whether these journals are on JCR.

In particular, the DOAJ search results for open access journals in Computer Science with zero publication charges are at [this URL](http://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22:%7B%22filtered%22:%7B%22query%22:%7B%22match_all%22:%7B%7D%7D,%22filter%22:%7B%22bool%22:%7B%22must%22:[%7B%22term%22:%7B%22_type%22:%22journal%22%7D%7D,%7B%22term%22:%7B%22index.classification.exact%22:%22Science%22%7D%7D,%7B%22term%22:%7B%22index.classification.exact%22:%22Electronic%20computers.%20Computer%20science%22%7D%7D,%7B%22term%22:%7B%22bibjson.author_pays.exact%22:%22N%22%7D%7D]%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D).

In principle, as a next step one could compare (by hand or perhaps using some software) the list resulting from the DOAJ search with the list from JCR for (a given branch of) computer science or search in JCR (e.g. in [the list of full journal titles](http://admin-apps.webofknowledge.com/JCR/JCR?RQ=TITLES_FULL)) for specific journal names.

Also, the DOAJ listing includes links to home pages of journals and often data about the journal impact factor (if any) or JCR listing are available at these home pages.

To give a specific example resulting from a quick attempt to compare the lists, the [Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research](http://www.jair.org) is open access with zero publication charges and has a 2013 IF of 0.904.

Answer (score 1):

There are many journals that satisfy your criteria… here's how to find them!

1. Use [Journal Citation Reports](http://admin-apps.webofknowledge.com/JCR/JCR?RQ=HOME)
2. Search journals by publisher:
   [image]
3. Choose an open access publisher, such as “Public Library of Science”
   [image]
4. Enjoy!
   [image]

---

**Edit:** as JeffE wisely noted, this does not address the criterion of “no publishing charge”. You'll have to check the various journals, but some have no publishing charges, including some published by [Hindawi Publishing Corporation](http://www.hindawi.com/apc/) for example. To find out which, **cross-reference the JCR data with [this list](http://www.lib.berkeley.edu/scholarlycommunication/oa_fees.html) maintained by Berkeley**.

Comment: This does not address his third criterion: **free to publish**.  Many (most?) open access publishers require authors to pay significant publication fees, [including PLOS](http://www.plos.org/publish/pricing-policy/publication-fees/).

Comment: Another pitfall is that some open-access journal can be published by publishers that also publish traditional journals, i.e. are not "open-access publisher". An example would be Forum of Mathematics, published by Cambridge University press (but this one plans to charge APC soon).

Answer (score -2):

Sherpa Romeo, http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/, might be helpful to you, as well.  I think you'd still have to do your cross-check against the JCR, though.