# How to search for an open access journal with no publication fee?

Tags: publications, online-publication

I'm having some trouble trying to find a place to publish. Therefore this question is about how to find these places.

For this I provide the following example, my particular case.

I'm searching for:

- A journal, not a conference, workshop, etc.
- Where publishing is free (no cost for processing the paper)
- That is open access (no cost for readers)
- Where the reviews are transparent/public. I.e. anyone can follow the review process
- Where my drafts are also public (for people to follow the review process) The point is that I would like not to need arxiv.org or similar services to dissuade reviewers from shifty actions
- In the field of computer science theory (like lambda calculus and such)
- LaTeX should be accepted, this is very important
- I don't need trees dying, online publishing is fine
- I don't care about impact factors, as long as the journal is trustworthy

This is my particular case, but I'd like to make clear that I'm not asking for this specific fish for me, but for a good method about how to fish that can be useful for everybody in academia, specially those that are new and do not have this kind of knowledge.

PD: maybe a workaround would be using two services where one should be. Now I am thinking about uploading the paper to arxiv.org (or similar) and asking for reviews and comments on cstheory (or similar). I think that would meet all requirements and *implicit* requirements (implicit for journals) as allowing citations on my paper, proving authorship, etc. I'm not sure about being overlooking something or which considerations should be done to find the right place(s) to publish in this new context.

Comment: I've edited your title to be a bit more specific, featuring your three main criteria.

Comment: Open access journals which also don't charge a publication fee are quite rare. I think that journals published by scholarly/professional societies might satisfy this criteria in some cases. In those cases they would be funded by universities or member fees. However, I've no specific knowledge about computer science. Note that in some cases if you are unable to pay, "reputable" open access journals will waive the fee.

Comment: Putting aside open drafts and peer review, see also this question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11536/how-to-find-oa-free-to-publish-journals-with-a-jcr-ranking#comment21275_11536

Comment: @YoavKallus thank you, I did notice that question some time ago but please note that I'm not asking for specific journals but a way to search for them (something better than simply using Google, which is not of much help in this case).

Comment: @faheem - in fact roughly 70% of the journals in the DOAJ do not charge a publication fee...

Comment: @DavidRoberts: What is the DOAJ?

Comment: Directory of Open Access Journals

Comment: The question in the title is a duplicate of http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11536/how-to-find-oa-free-to-publish-journals-with-a-jcr-ranking#comment21275_11536.  You should make the title more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this link http://doaj.org/doaj?func=csv  to download the complete list of journals from DOAJ, with metadata as scientific field, license (if CC) and whether you have to pay to publish.

Comment: The fee field in that file seems to be empty.

Answer (score 13):

The set of journals you are describing is almost *guaranteed* to be equivalent to the null set. You are specifying way too many criteria on the journal. You are basically asking for a complete wish list that no single journal can reasonably satisfy and still survive. For instance:

- How does it pay its ISP hosting bill?
- Who handles the processing and editing of articles?
- Who does the typesetting and copyediting?
- Who maintains the web site?

All of these things require labor, and is not something that anyone is likely willing to donate *pro bono*. That means income has to come from somewhere.

Some of these criteria are not problems (for example, a CS journal is unlikely to refuse a LaTeX submission). However, in total, I think you really need to decide which criteria are required, and which ones would be nice to have. Then prioritize accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's what I thought, but I was ensured that there are [many](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11536#comment-21274) and even [thousands](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11536#comment-21340) of journals that meet those criteria. Now I am thinking about uploading the paper to [arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/) and asking for reviews and comments on [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) or a similar place. I'd be using two services instead of one, but I think that would meet all requirements. Do you think this is worthy of a new question?

Comment: _almost guaranteed to be equivalent to the null set_ — Journal of Machine Learning Research.  Electronic Journal of Combinatorics.  Journal of Graph Algorithms and Applications.  Journal of Computational Geometry.

Comment: _How does it pay its ISP hosting bill?_ Donated by the editor's university, run on a free wordpress or google site, or paid by a whopping $5/month donation by one of the editors. _Who handles the processing and editing of articles?_ Software and volunteer editors. _Who does the typesetting and copyediting?_  The authors. _Who maintains the web site?_ Software and volunteer editors.

Comment: @JeffE: Where are the public reviews for the journals you've listed? Where are the previous drafts?

Comment: @Trylks: Your original question didn't include open drafts and a public review process. Those additional criteria are vastly cutting down on the number of feasible solutions. As for how to handle the change in question—the question isn't so different. (You could basically ask this as a "subcase" of the original question, so I wouldn't spawn off a new question.)

Comment: I don't mean to sound provocative, but saying "is not something that anyone is likely willing to donate pro bono" strikes me as just a little curious in an academic setting. The two most important, difficult and time-consuming functions performed in academic publication, namely writing the articles and reviewing them, are done pro-bono, as everyone knows. These days authors also essentially do their own typesetting and proofreading. The journals are increasingly doing less and less. I think with some institutional support from universities, OA free to publish journals are quite practicable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [link](http://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22:%7B%22filtered%22:%7B%22query%22:%7B%22match_all%22:%7B%7D%7D,%22filter%22:%7B%22bool%22:%7B%22must%22:[%7B%22term%22:%7B%22bibjson.author_pays.exact%22:%22N%22%7D%7D]%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D) for DOAJ search listing open access journals specifically involving the no-author-charges condition, and [another one](http://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22:%7B%22filtered%22:%7B%22query%22:%7B%22match_all%22:%7B%7D%7D,%22filter%22:%7B%22bool%22:%7B%22must%22:[%7B%22term%22:%7B%22_type%22:%22journal%22%7D%7D,%7B%22term%22:%7B%22index.classification.exact%22:%22Science%22%7D%7D,%7B%22term%22:%7B%22index.classification.exact%22:%22Electronic%20computers.%20Computer%20science%22%7D%7D,%7B%22term%22:%7B%22bibjson.author_pays.exact%22:%22N%22%7D%7D]%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D) restricted to the computer science (again with zero publication charges, of course).

Unfortunately, I do not quite see how to restrict the results of the above searches to meet your other criteria(accepting (La)TeX submissions etc.) without checking the specific journals by hand.